# Swift4 : Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have created an App using xcode 10 and use swift 4.

I am getting an error:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

I started to use NavigationController, and now I get an error. When doing Segue in the state before use, no error occurred.
I checked for Typo's etc, but there is no problem.

Error is this part

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0 :
    //Price Cell
    let priceCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "priceCell", for: indexPath) as? priceTableViewCell

    //Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    if let price:String = store![indexPath.row].price{
        priceCell?.priceLabel.text! = price
    }else{
        priceCell?.priceLabel.text! = "-"
    }
    return priceCell!

    case 1 :
    //timeCell

        let timeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "timeCell", for: indexPath) as? timeTableViewCell

        if let time:String = store![indexPath.row].open_time{
            timeCell?.timeLabel.text! = time
        }else{
            timeCell?.timeLabel.text! = "-"
        }
    return timeCell!

    case 2 :
    //closedayCell
    let closedayCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "closedayCell", for: indexPath) as? closedayTableViewCell

    if let closeday:String = store![indexPath.row].closed_day{
        closedayCell?.closedayLabel.text! = closeday
    }else{
        closedayCell?.closedayLabel.text! = "-"
    }


    return closedayCell!

    default :
        print("Default Selected")
    }
    return cell
}
```

**Store View Controller All view**

```
import UIKit

class StoreViewController: 
    UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,  
    UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UITableViewDelegate, 
    UITableViewDataSource {


    var store_id = ""
    var store : [Store]?
    var photoPath : [Store.photos]?
    var tag : [Store.tags]?
    var selectedImage : UIImage?
    let defaultValues = UserDefaults.standard


    @IBOutlet weak var imageCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var UIView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tagCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        //Collectiopn DetaSources
        imageCollectionView.dataSource = self
        imageCollectionView.delegate = self

        tagCollectionView.dataSource = self
        tagCollectionView.delegate = self

        //UIView Shadow
        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: UIView.bounds)
        UIView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        UIView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        UIView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        UIView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        UIView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath

        //Request API
        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/store/api?store_id=" + store_id)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let encoder: JSONEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

        session.dataTask(with: request){(data, response, error)in if error == nil,
            let data = data,
            let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse{

            let decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
            do {

                let json = try decoder.decode(Store.self, from: data)

                if json != nil {
                    print(json)
                }else{
                    print("nil")
                }
                self.store = [json]
                self.photoPath = json.photos
                self.tag = json.tags

                if let imageURL = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/photos/" + json.photos[0].path){
                    DispatchQueue.global().async {
                        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
                        if let data = data {
                            let image = UIImage(data: data)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.mainImage.image = image
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.nameLabel.text = json.name
                    self.locationLabel.text = json.location

                }

            } catch {
                print("error:", error.localizedDescription)

            }

            }

            }.resume()

        //print(defaultValues.string(forKey: "id"))


        // Image Collection view Layout
        let itemSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3.62 - 3.62

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemSize, height: itemSize)

        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1

        imageCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout

        // Tag Collection View
        let tagLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        tagLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
        tagLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        tagLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        tagLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 80, height: 24)
        tagCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = tagLayout

        print("storeID is"+store_id)
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    //        UI coner redius
        let uiViewPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: UIView.bounds, 
        byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8))
        let uiViewMask = CAShapeLayer()
        uiViewMask.path = uiViewPath.cgPath
        UIView.layer.mask = uiViewMask

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //Collection
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == self.imageCollectionView{
            let imageCell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell",for: indexPath)
            let imageView = imageCell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

            let imageURL = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/photos/" + photoPath![indexPath.row].path)
            if imageURL == nil {
                print("nil")
            }else{
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL!)
                    if let data = data {
                        let image = UIImage(data: data)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            imageCell.layer.masksToBounds = true;
                            imageCell.layer.cornerRadius = 3
                            imageView.image = image
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            return imageCell

         //Tag collection view
        }else if collectionView == self.tagCollectionView{
            let tagCell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Tag",for: indexPath)
            let tagLabel = tagCell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel

                tagLabel.text! = tag![indexPath.row].name

            tagCell.layer.cornerRadius = 12
            return tagCell


        }else{
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
    }




    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }


    func tagcollectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tag?.count ?? 0
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        switch section {
        case 0:
            return 1
        case 1 :
            return 1
        case 2 :
            return 1
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }


    //Collection view tap
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if collectionView == self.imageCollectionView{
            if photoPath![indexPath.row].path != nil {
                if let imageURL = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/photos/" + photoPath![indexPath.row].path ){
                    DispatchQueue.global().async {
                        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
                        if let data = data {
                            let image = UIImage(data: data)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.mainImage.image = image
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                print("error")
                return
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0 :
        //Price Cell
        let priceCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "priceCell", for: indexPath) as? priceTableViewCell

        if let price:String = store![indexPath.row].price{
            priceCell?.priceLabel.text! = price
        }else{
            priceCell?.priceLabel.text! = "-"
        }
        return priceCell!

        case 1 :
        //timeCell

            let timeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "timeCell", for: indexPath) as? timeTableViewCell

            if let time:String = store![indexPath.row].open_time{
                timeCell?.timeLabel.text! = time
            }else{
                timeCell?.timeLabel.text! = "-"
            }
        return timeCell!

        case 2 :
        //closedayCell
        let closedayCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "closedayCell", for: indexPath) as? closedayTableViewCell

        if let closeday:String = store![indexPath.row].closed_day{
            closedayCell?.closedayLabel.text! = closeday
        }else{
            closedayCell?.closedayLabel.text! = "-"
        }

        return closedayCell!

        default :
            print("Default Selected")
        }
        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func moreImageBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        let store_id = self.store_id
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toStorePhotoViewController", sender: store_id)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toStorePhotoViewController"{
            let storePhotoViewController = segue.destination as! StorePhotoViewController
            storePhotoViewController.store_id = sender as! String
        }
    }

    //Bookmark Button
    @IBAction func bookmarkBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        let user_id = defaultValues.string(forKey: "userId")
        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/api/store/favorite?")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        // POSTを指定
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        // POSTするデータをBodyとして設定
        let postParameters = "user_id=" + user_id! + "&store_id=" + store_id
        request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: .utf8)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil, let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                // HTTPヘッダの取得
                print("Content-Type: \(response.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"] ?? "")")
                // HTTPステータスコード
                print("statusCode: \(response.statusCode)")
                print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    @IBAction func locationBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        let lat = store![0].lat
        let lng = store![0].lng

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!){
            let urlStr : String = "comgooglemaps://?daddr=\(lat),\(lng)&directionsmode=walking&zoom=14"
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:urlStr)!,options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }else{
            let daddr = String(format: "%f,%f", lat, lng)
            let urlString = "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=\(daddr)&dirflg=w"
            let encodeUrl = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

            let url = URL(string: encodeUrl)!
            UIApplication.shared.open(url,options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't force unwrap. it looks like store may not have values in.

Comment: Declare your store array as: `var store : [Store] = []` and get rid of any kind of force unwrapping (`!`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare array as below

```
var store = [Store]()
```

Change TableView datasource as per below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        switch section {
        case 0:
            return store.count > 0 ? 1 : 0 // if array count greater than return 1 else 0
        case 1 :
            return store.count > 0 ? 1 : 0
        case 2 :
            return store.count > 0 ? 1 : 0
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you answer. I can't get table list use this code.
No Error

Comment: Please add that code where you list array filled

Comment: `var store = [Store]()`  and use arry this code `if let price:String = store[indexPath.row].price`

Comment: this morning fix my code and use you're answer code I got data.
I use a guard.  thank you so much

Comment: @Alex Welcome..

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Scriptable, You should not force unwrap.

You can add Exception break point for break point navigator like below 
[image]

And then 
[image]

This will help to pin point issue, Hopefully.